# How to get the extra information by hovering over class in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How to get the extra information by hovering over class in visual studio. Let me show you what I found in a video I was watching and comparison with my Visual Studio for the same class. We both are using VS 2015.

[image]

Comment: Looks just fine on my machine.  Be sure to apply the updates (mine got as far as Update 2), beware of add-ins.

Comment: I applied the updates. it is still the same. not sure what else to check